# Ignore invalid messages in reply channel of TcpOutboundGateway and wait for another reply of same output channel message

Tags: spring-integration

I have a specific requirement to digest some unwanted message types in the reply channel of `TcpOutboundGateway` and continue waiting until it comes with a valid message.

I send a message in output channel of `TcpOutboundGateway` and get an acknowledgment in reply channel. But there are chances I might get an invalid acknowledgment message for the sent message. So I should ignore the invalid message got in reply channel and still wait for a valid message to come.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AbstractConnectionFactory` can be supplied with the:

```
public void setInterceptorFactoryChain(TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain interceptorFactoryChain) {
```

The `TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain` should be supplied with the custom `TcpConnectionInterceptorFactory` to produce some custom `TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport` to intercept that message in the overridden `public boolean onMessage(Message<?> message) {` and don't let it go to the `super.onMessage()`.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#ip-interceptors).